# Superimpose masked video onto video in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I currently have a video that has been selected out with a mask and saved as a separate video. The surrounded regions of the mask are all black. I want to superimpose this mask video onto another video of the same dimensions, replacing the black pixels with the pixels in the underlying video. Is this sort of thing possible in Matlab?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way out could be to extract frames from both the videos and replace all the black pixels of the first video with the corresponding pixel values from the second video.